# SharePoint SPFx: How to find package-solution.json - - Total Beginner in Over Their Head

Tags: sharepoint, spfx, sharepointframework

I am trying to access SharePoint via an API. I am getting a 403 code and was told I need to add six lines of code to the package-solution.json file but I have not a clue where to find it. I tried using command line to open in Visual Studio but I can't find the pre-existing file and it just keeps making a new file.

Any advice on how to find the file?

I am in the very beginning stages of learning APIs and don't know all the obvious things.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Open visual studio code on your computer
2. Click File --> Open Folder from top left corner
3. Open the folder where your SharePoint SPFx solution code is saved
4. Once you open the folder, use `Ctrl + P` and search for `package-solution`
5. You will get the search result of the files --> click on file name in search results to open the file:

[image]

---

You can also find the file in file explorer tree inside VS code:

[image]